# Using PDO to echo display all rows from a table

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to echo out all the rows of a table using PDO but am running into trouble.

With the old way of doing I'd have done it like

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $title= $row['title'];
   $body= $row['body'];
}
```

But with PDO I'm trying;

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT title, body FROM post");
$result->execute();

while ($row = $db->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$title = $row['title'];
$body = $row['body'];
}

echo $title;
echo $body;
```

Which keeps giving me Call to undefined method PDO::fetchAll()

Doing the example given in the manual

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
?>
```

Works, but I don't think I have control over the individual colums like I would with a $row=['blah']; do I? It also prints out like this; rather ugly:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => This is the test title entered in the database[0]

What needs to be done to properly use PDO to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change:

```
while ($row = $db->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$title = $row['title'];
$body = $row['body'];
}
```

to:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$title = $row['title'];
$body = $row['body'];
}
```

Comment: This seems to be giving me a similar error

 Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetch()

Comment: I changed my answer, try again... ($db should be $result)

Comment: Thanks John. Please excuse the ignorance though, but where does the $result come from? It's giving me an undefined variable error.

Comment: look in your post and find the variable $result? Could be $sth, I dont know what version of you post you are using...

Comment: Hahaha oh boy, don't I look a fool. Changed that in my code due to fabs answer and forgot about it.

Got it working now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Which keeps giving me Call to undefined method PDO::fetchAll()

This should have given you the hint, that you are using the wrong object. It's [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetchall) as you can see in your second example, or if you want to use it in a while loop [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetch):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $title = $row['title'];
    $body = $row['body'];
}
```

Additional notes:

1. `$result` is a misleading variable name as you might see from the `$result->execute()` line. You don't execute a *result*, you execute a *statement*. This is why in the manual `$stmt` or `$sth` (statement handle i guess) are used.
2. The `echo` lines should be inside the while loop, otherwise you overwrite again and again, then output only the last row.

Comment: Thanks fab, I've made the necessary changes and it's helped me solved the problem.