# PDO returns just last row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wanna ask why I am getting just last row from DB, while I'm using fetchAll(); function? As a control for myself, I have added  to see what I'll get.... The result is same... No metter what I select from  tag, I'm getting only last row...

The code is next:

```
 <form method="post" action="index.php">

    <select name="namrli" onChange="location.reload()"><option value="0">Test?</option>         


<?php 

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Server ORDER BY id");

    $query->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id']));

    $result = $query->fetchAll();

    foreach ($result as $row) { 

    $srvid = $row['id'];

    $srvname = $row['Naziv'];

    $srvslot = $row['Slotovi'];

    $srvprice = $row['Cena'];


?>

<option value = "<?php $srvid;?>" selected="selected" name="ServerID"><?php echo $srvname; echo " - "; echo $srvslot; echo " - "; echo $srvprice;?></option>


    <?php           

    }
?>  



<input type="text" value="<?php echo $srvid; ?>" name="ServerID" />
</select>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>" name="KorisnikID" /> 

<input type="submit" name="poruci" value="poruči" id="" />


</form>
```

I am stucked here....

Comment: Have you verified how many rows the query returned? Have you checked the HTML output your script generates? And btw. `input` can not be inside `select`, that’s invalid HTML.

Comment: you don't need this `$query->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id']));`

Comment: You have a text input inside a select tag, that's not a valid html `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $srvid; ?>" name="ServerID" />
</select>`

Comment: you didn't bind anything in values and should have clearly thrown an error about it http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: `$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Server where id = :id ORDER BY id");` think thts what u need

Comment: @Your Common Sense , this makes a better duplicate than what u have chosen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491430/using-pdo-to-echo-display-all-rows-from-a-table

Comment: Sorry to moderators, but this post u marked as duplicate has something else.... I AM GETTING all of the data in     <select>, but whn I try to     echo, I am getting only last item....

Comment: @ Masivuye Cokile: Now I am not getting any of results.....